# Power BI equivalent of Excel SUMIF

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I am really battling to wrap my mind around this problem as Power BI can only reference (& filter) columns and not individual cells. To explain, consider the following table:
NAME.      NUMBER
Ben.       20
John.      10
Ben.       -5
John.      7
James.     3

I would like to get it into the following format in Power BI:
NAME.      NUMBER
Ben.       15
John.      17
James.     3

In Excel this is pretty simple with sumif but I can't seem to crack this in Power BI. I can't filter on the name column because it is the sum of the individual names that I want. I can calculate the NAME column easily enough using DISTINCT(NAME) but not the NUMBER column. Any ideas?

I could pull the data into Excel and calculate with unique values and a vlookup but given the size of the database this is impractical

Comment: Create a measure =SUM([Number]) and then add a matrix to the canvas. Put the Name column on Rows and then the measure goes into the Values. And that's it. You should get one row for each Name and then a corresponding total.